# Refused to display/connect when previewing entry on multi-site setup

Tags: control-panel, htaccess, live-preview

I run a multi-site setup with four sites; one on unicorn.com and one on all-your-base.com.

The way Craft CMS licensing works, you can run multiple sites on different domains on the same license/install, but you have to edit all the sites from just one domain - unicorn.com in this case.

When I click "live preview", from unicorn.com all I see is a sad pixelated face and a message saying "all-your-base.com refused to connect."

[image: sad face saying "refused to connect"]

Console says: "Refused to display 'https://all-your-base.com/...' in a frame because it set X-Frame-Options to 'sameorigin'

[image: Refused to display 'https://domain.com/...' in a frame because it set X-Frame-Options to 'sameorigin']

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### X-Frame-Options

The problem is that your site's .htaccess file prevents unicorn.com from viewing all-your-base.com in an iframe because the `X-Frame-Options` header has not been configured for allowing this.

[Securing Craft](https://craftcms.com/guides/securing-craft#set-security-headers-for-the-front-end-site) mentions that you have to add headers for:

- Strict-Transport-Security
- X-Frame-Options X-XSS-Protection
- X-Content-Type-Options
- Content-Security-Policy
- Public-Key-Pins

So although the following `.htaccess`-code doesn't add all of these headers, they together make the "refused to connect" go away, by allowing the `frame-ancestor` to be unicorn.com even when previewing content on all-your-base.com in an iframe (which is how the preview works).

```bsh
# Unset X-Frame-Options that has been previously set possibly by Craft 
Header unset X-Frame-Options

# Allow unicorn.com to request itself in iframes (for live preview)
Header always set X-Frame-Options "ALLOW-FROM https://unicorn.com/"

# Allow unicorn.com to request all-your-base.com in iframes (for live preview)
Header set Content-Security-Policy "frame-ancestors unicorn.com"
```

These headers are simply strings that are attached to - you guessed it - the header of the HTML-page that is transmitted from the server.

It's up to the  browser how to interpret them. `Content-Security-Policy` is for instance [not supported on IE11](https://caniuse.com/#search=csp).

In this case, `Content-Security-Policy` is used by Chrome and `X-Frame-Options` is [used by IE11](https://caniuse.com/#search=X-Frame-Options) and others.

### Access-Control-Allow-Origin

You might also get error messages in the console because Access-Control-Allow-Origin is missing. Here is an example of setting that header. Note that it doesn't support multiple domains, so here I serve the local development address together with the production site address using the `SetEnvIf` command:

```bsh
SetEnvIf Origin "http(s)?://?(unicorn.com|unicorn.local)$" AccessControlAllowOrigin=$0
Header add Access-Control-Allow-Origin %{AccessControlAllowOrigin}e env=AccessControlAllowOrigin
Header merge Vary Origin
Header set Access-Control-Allow-Credentials "true"
```